# Is there a Python function equivalent to R's binom.confint(x, n, methods = 'lrt')?

Tags: python, r, statistics, confidence-interval

I'm having trouble finding an implementation of a binomial confidence interval done with a Likelihood-Ratio Test.

I ran an extensive Google search and found implementations of binomial confidence interval and lrt, but none that combined both.